# Loop through XML children from AJAX call using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I need help with Ajax and jQuery.

I have received this XML data from Ajax call:

```
<data>
<book title=“Book1” bookID="1">
<AuthorsNum>3</AuthorsNum>
<author>
    <authorId>1</authorId>
    <fName> Mark </fName>
    <mName>null</mName>
    <lName>White</lName>
    <education>PHD</education>
    <role>Writer</role>     
</author>
<author>
    <authorId>2</authorId>
    <fName>Jhon</fName>
    <mName>null</mName>
    <lName>Brown</lName>
    <education>PHD</education>
    <role>Writer</role>     
</author>
</book>
<book title=“Book2” bookID=“2”>
<AuthorsNum>4</AuthorsNum>
<author>
    <authorId>1</authorId>
    <fName> Mark </fName>
    <mName>null</mName>
    <lName>White</lName>
    <education>PHD</education>
    <role>Writer</role>     
</author>
</book>
```

I need to create a drop down (select) menu with book names and ids. Then, when each book is selected I need to display authors name and education. For now, I get the drop down list, but I can not figure out how I get the selected book and loop through all the authors for this book to display them.

Here is what I have done:

```
printAuthors = function(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        async: true,
        cache: false,
        url: url,
        data: {path: "/mypath" },
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function(data, status){

            var myContent = "";
            if( $(data).find("error").length!=0){

            }

            else{
                var selectElement = $("<select id='bookMenu' name='bookMenu' />");
                var content="";
                $( "book", data).each( function() {
                    $("<option />", {value: $(this).attr('bookID') , text: $(this).attr('title') }).appendTo(selectElement);

                    var selectedOption = this.value;
                    $( "author", $(data).find('book[bookID="' + selectedOption + '"]').children()).each( function() {
                        // get the name and education and append them to a #myDiv
                    });
                });

                $( "#myDiv").html( selectElement ) ;


            }
        }

    });
}
```

Can anyone help? Is there a better approach to implement the menu and results?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so it seems simple:

1. after creating select option you need to exit the loop first.
2. After that add onchange event on your select (refer to jquery onchange event), this will give you the selected option.
3. Loop through the xml and compare your value with the data, append your data accordingly on a div.

Second approach:

1. By defautl append the entire data in different div's and keep their display as none
2. Match the selected value in select and display the div's which matches as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Perfect example of when to use [data-](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Using_data_attributes) attributes, [here](http://html5doctor.com/html5-custom-data-attributes/) is another simpler intro on the attributes.

```
$("book", data).each(function () {

    //NOTE: this solution assumes names and edus are the same length. (every author has an education).
    //add logic if not the case
    var authors = "";
    var authors_edu = "";

    $(this).find('author').each(function () {
        authors += $(this).find('fName').text() + " " + $(this).find('lName').text() + ", ";
        authors_edu += $(this).find('education').text() + ", ";
    });

    //remove trailing comma
    if (authors.lastIndexOf(",") == authors.length - 2) {
        authors = authors.substr(0, authors.length - 2);
        authors_edu = authors_edu.substr(0, authors_edu.length - 2);
    }

    selectElement.append($("<option>").attr('value', $(this).attr('bookID'))
        .text($(this).attr('title'))
        .attr('data-auth-name', authors)
        .attr('data-auth-edu', authors_edu)
        .on('click', function () {
            var names = $(this).attr('data-auth-name').split(',');
            var edus = $(this).attr('data-auth-edu').split(',');

            $('#myTable > tbody').empty();

            for (var i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
                $('#myTable > tbody:last-child').append('<tr><td>' + names[i] + '</td><td>' + edus[i] + '</td></tr>');
            }
        }));

    var selectedOption = this.value;
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
<div id="myDiv2">
    <table id="myTable">
        <thead><tr><th>Author Name</th><th>Education</th></tr></thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I have altered the code to meet your "table" requirements as stated in comments. This solution should do for your case.

Another option is to create a global list of author objects and assign book_id's to them then on "change" of the select list look up all authors from the list linked to that book_id.

Comment: I need to display the data into  a table as author name and his education for each authors. So, how I can get the table populated from the two list.

Comment: @F.Fo I have updated my answer, just add styling to your table and should be hundreds.